# Retarded time Lienard Wiechert potential

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, lienard-wiechert

In a potential which needs to be evaluated at the retarded time, is this the time which represents the actual time the "physics" occurred? So $t_{\text{ret}}=t-\frac{r}{c}$, not just because it may be that you are receiving a signal at light speed but because "causality" spreads out at the maximum speed, $c$, is this correct?

The Lienard-Wiechert 4-potential for some point charge ($q$):  $A^\mu=\frac{q u^\mu}{4\pi \epsilon_0 u^\nu r^\nu}$ where $r^\nu$ represents the 4-vector for the distance from the observer. In the rest frame of the charge $A^i$ for $i=1,2,3$ is clearly zero but from what has been said about the retarded time we have that $A^0=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0c(t-r/c)}$.

Obviously I would like to get $A^0=-\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r}$, so where is the misunderstanding of retarded time and instantaneous time? Unless we would like the time since the signal was emitted which is $r/c$? Or if $t$ itself is already $t'-r/c$ and we need to return to the instantaneous time $t$, when the signal was emitted.

Answer (score 2):

Actually since charge is at rest $u_{\nu}r^{\nu} = u_0 r^0 = ct'$ where $t'$ is retarded time,  $t'=r/c$, where $r$ is the (constant) distance to the charge.

Answer (score 2):

It's an implicit relation
$$t_- = t - \frac{R}{c}, \quad R = ||, \quad  =  - (t_-),$$
where $t ↦ (t)$ is the trajectory of the point source, and $ = \dot{}(t_-)$ is its velocity evaluated at time $t_-$.

The three relations between $t_-$, $R$ and $$ determine them as implicit functions of $\left(,t\right)$, and a functional of the trajectory $t ↦ (t)$. It is well-defined if $|| < c$.

If you differentiate each relation:
$$dt_- = dt - \frac{dR}{c}, \quad dR = \frac{·d}{R}, \quad d = d - (t_-)dt_-,$$
you can solve for $dt_-$, $dR$ and $d$ in closed form to get:
$$
dt_- = \frac{Rc dt - ·d}{Rc - ·}, \quad
dR = \frac{c·(d - dt)}{Rc - ·}, \quad
d = \frac{Rc(d - dt) + ×(×d)}{Rc - ·}.
$$
Thus, for instance, plucking out the differential coefficients of $t_-$, we get:
$$
\frac{∂t_-}{∂t} = \frac{Rc}{Rc - ·}, \quad ∇t_- = -\frac{}{Rc - ·}.
$$

The potential 1-form $A ≡ A_x dx + A_y dy + A_z dz - φ dt = ·d - φ dt$ is given at the space-time point $\left(,t\right)$ by:
$$A\left(,t\right) = \frac{e}{4πε_0c} \frac{·d - c² dt}{Rc - ·}.$$

If the charge is stationary, with $(t) = $, then $ = $, $R = r ≡ ||$, $t_- = t - r/c$ and $ = $, with the potential 1-form thus reducing to the following:
$$A = -\frac{e dt}{4πε_0r},$$
or, component-wise, to $ = $ and $φ = e/{4πε_0r}$, which is independent of $t$, so is also the advanced potential.

The potential is derived (in component form) here:

**Liénard–Wiechert potential**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential

and issues concerning the method used with the delta functions (and corrections entailed, when done properly) are described in the reference here:

**On the Lienard-Wiechert potentials**
https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:22061421